# list.count(x) in 2D list python

Tags: python-3.x

im very new to python, Im trying to count how many x I have in a 2D array, but list.count(x) gives me 0, but i know its not zero.

Im showing all my code. This code should do: read name and age from file, take maximum and minimum age and print in other file ALL with the same maximum and minimum age.

```
with open("duomenys.txt") as d: 
   sar = [line.split() for line in d]
max = 0
min = 200

for index, item in enumerate(sar):
    if int(sar[index][1]) > max:
        max = int(sar[index][1])
        pozmax = index

for index, item in enumerate(sar):
    if int(sar[index][1]) < min:
        min = int(sar[index][1])
        pozmin = index

with open('vyr_jaun.txt', 'w') as d: 
    d.write (sar[pozmin][0]+' '+sar[pozmin][1]+'\n')
with open('vyr_jaun.txt', 'a') as d: 
    d.write (sar[pozmax][0]+' '+sar[pozmax][1])
```

this writes only one name and age in file

my duomneys.txt file:

```
Justas 23
Mantas 18
Rokas 33
Anzelmute 69
Ruta 11
Vilius 2
Monika 6
Petras 17
Stasys 26
Zose 13
Jurgis 2
Borisas 69
```

Comment: I do not understand how your question is related to the piece of code you're showing. Where do you `count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(note that your ages in the array are strings.  This is not a problem.)

```
what = str(9) # whatever you are searching for
count = 0
for name,age in array:
    if age == what:
        count += 1

print("there are",count,"people with the age",what)
```

Comment: But i have only 1 list. `[['Justas', '23'], ['Mantas', '18'], ['Rokas', '33'], ['Anzelmute', '69'], ['Ruta', '11'], ['Vilius', '2'], ['Monika', '6'], ['Petras', '17'], ['Stasys', '26'], ['Zose', '13'], ['Jurgis', '2'], ['Borisas', '69']]`